# Can I disable Dragon Professional Individual's automatic capitalization in some programs?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Can I disable Dragon Professional Individual's automatic capitalization in some programs?

---

I.e., in some programs, I would like Dragon to let me decide when to capitalize a letter. E.g.,:

- if I say `period print`, Dragon would normally transcribe `. Print`, but I want it to transcribe `. print`
- when I go to a new line,  Dragon sometimes capitalize the first letter of the first word I dictate.

Dragon Professional Individual was formerly known as Dragon NaturallySpeaking. I am interested in any version of Dragon above 12.0.

I use Dragon on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocabulary is the same for every application.

This was the case in Dragon 12, and it's still like that in Dragon 15 either. You can't determine a word's behaviour in different programs like you can for application-dependent commands.

There are some partial solutions that depend on you giving the command:

- You can either force small case by saying "no-caps" before the word. You can say "period no-caps print" and it will write `. print`
- Or you say "no-caps on" if you want to continually dictate without capitalisation.  E.g. dictate "no caps on Green Eggs and Ham by Dr. Seuss" it will write `green eggs and ham by dr. seuss` in lowercase and everything thereafter. To end this, you say "no caps off".

There is a help article that gives you an overview of this behaviour: 
http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/customer-portal/documentation/userguide/chapter6/ug_chapter6_capitalize_text.asp

To sum up, you can only do this on a case by case basis.

If you want to push it, you'd have to write a program that activates the no caps on when you switch to a program. Or you write a script that will paste the text in the desired format with a search and replace macro running on the clipboard.